# How to determine the store directory from a Neo4j graph database?

Tags: neo4j

The `BatchInserter` provides a method called `getStoreDir` that delivers the store directory of the graph database. However, `GraphDatabaseService` doesn't offer such a capability. Only the deprecated `GraphDatabaseAPI` offers a deprecated method `getStoreDir`. So is there any opportunity to determine the store directory of a Neo4j graph database via their APIs?

Comment: Also GraphDatabaseAPI will stay around for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Configuration` JMX bean, it has a `store_dir` attribute, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/jmx-mxbeans.html#jmx-configuration for details.

See http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-jmx.html how to query JMX beans from Java.